# How to get the status of a process running in background using system command?

Tags: linux, process, system

I want to get the status of a process running in the background using the system function.
I want to read the status of process inside the programme.

I am running a process of playing a video in the background. I want to monitor this process so that when this process completes I will play another video.

If I am playing it in the foreground and if I want to kill this process then I am not able to kill the process as it is blocking the main process.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for [jobs](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ujobs.htm) command.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. I know about jobs command but, I want to read the status of a process in the same program. So, that just after finishing it I can play the next video.

Answer (score 0):

you can use command “jobs”

```
[root@localhost src]# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./redis-server
[2]+  Running                 tail -f /var/log/messages &
```

that will show you what jobs is running in the background.

"bg" can start the num 1 program

```
 bg 1
```

"fg" can put the running in the background to the foreground

if you want kill this process ,

```
ps -ef
```

find the process PID, if you can't kill, then kill the PPID

```
kill -9 `pgrep program`
```